# How to exclude string of patten in regex search

Tags: python, regex

How to use regex to search word in the html string, but ignore the word in html tags. For example `<a href="foo">foo</a>`, the first `foo` in  should be ignored, the second `foo` is the pattern to search.

Comment: Are you looking for a bullet-proof solution? Or one that works with just that specific string?

Comment: Instead of regex, you should use an HTML parser. Try `beautifulsoup`

Comment: The `foo` could be regex express.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. I will have a try.

Comment: An approach that works in many cases is `<[^>]+>|(foo)`. From there you can find the matches that have a first capture group. It breaks though when the attributes contain `>`.

Comment: [`re.sub(r'<[^<]+?>|(foo)', lambda m: "<mark>{}</mark>".format(m.group(1)) if m.group(1) else m.group(), s)`](https://ideone.com/6Z2Zr0) will work in any Python version.

Answer (score 1):

An example using `BeautifulSoup` **combined with regex** instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

string = '''
<a class='fooo123'>foo on its own</a>
<a class='123foo'>only foo</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(string, "lxml")
foo_links = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("^foo"))
print(foo_links)
# ['foo on its own']
```

---

To ***wrap*** the found links with e.g. `mark`, you can do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

string = '''
<a class='fooo123'>foo on its own</a>
<a class='123foo'>only foo</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(string, "lxml")
foo_links = soup.findAll('a', text=re.compile("^foo"))
for a in foo_links:
    mark = soup.new_tag('mark')
    a.wrap(mark)

print(soup.prettify())
```

As well as the mandatory [**Tony the Pony**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) link...

Comment: Thanks for the example. The search works. Do you have any idea to highlight the matched item as well? Basically, replace the `foo` with `<mark>foo</mark>`. I also found that BeautifulSoup is much slower than `regex`, the search with `beautifulsoup` takes about 1.5 seconds while `regex` takes only 5ms (`re.compile("foo", string)`). Maybe because I do not have the correct search pattern? I also tried regex `re.compile("(?:<.*>.*)(foo)")`, it is even longer with 3.830 seconds.

Comment: @Tmx: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This program should be able to find all the contents between tags.

```
import re

str = '''<h3>
            <a href="//stackexchange.com/users/838793061/?accounts">yourcommunities</a>
    </h3>

        <a href="#" id="edit-pinned-sites">edit</a>
        <a href="#" id="cancel-pinned-sites"style="display:none;">cancel</a>'''

pattern = re.compile(r'>([^<>]+)<')
all = re.findall(pattern, str)

for i in all:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if the content contains spaces?

I propose the next regex that also removes the spaces from the answer:

```
#### With spaces:
line = '<a href="foo">     foo       </a>'
re.findall(r'>\s*(\w*)\s*<',line)
### ['foo']

#### No spaces:
line = '<a href="foo">foo</a>'
re.findall(r'>\s*(\w*)\s*<',line)
### ['foo']
```